# Directus interface using vue-datetime

Tags: vue.js, directus

I'm looking at creating my first Directus interface. Has anyone had any success using the vue-datetime picker (https://github.com/mariomka/vue-datetime) as part of a Directus interface? Is there another way to create a Directus date-time picker?

Answer (score 1):

Now days chrome and firefox has their own pickers for the `<input type="date">`. If you want to do you own just follow the instructions of

This intructions are for creating a interface
https://github.com/directus/directus/blob/main/docs/guides/extensions/interfaces.md

Use the actual date interface from the admin app for inspiration. https://github.com/directus/directus/tree/main/app/src/interfaces/datetime

The process to make a extension is simple

1. Create the extension with the toolkit.
2. Add Vue code.
3. Add your interface to a table

Comment: The links in your answer are now broken. Do you know if this feature was deprecated?

Comment: They are changing the way that extensions works for v9, i will update my answer